# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 for my string

Tags: python, string, split

I am trying to compare two strings within an if-else statement in python. My code is the following:

```
#_file = 'tests_1012_IEO_ANG_HI.pk'
_prts = _file.split("_") # _prts  = ['test', '1012', 'IEO', 'ANG', 'HI.pkl']
if (_prts[3] == "HAP"):
        label = 1
elif (_prts[3] == "SAD"):
        label = 2
elif (_prts[3] == "ANG"):
        label = 3
```

The `_file` variable is a string and by splitting it I am taking its substrings ['test', '1012', 'IEO', 'ANG', 'HI.pkl'] while the _file = 'tests_1012_IEO_ANG_HI.pk'

```
if (_prts[3] == "HAP"):
```

However, when I am trying to use the above if-else statement I am receiving the following error:

> if (_prts[3] == "HAP"): ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ANG'

What is exactly going on? I have checked the following code in debugging `_prts[3] == "ANG"`and the result is `True`. Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: What is in `_prts`? Please include its value in your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I have a string file = "asdfads_afsd_fads_ANG_adfs_..." and then I am trying to perform string split using underscore "_".

Comment: Couldn't reproduce that, so I think issue is not here.You may need to post a minimal example.

Comment: The problem is in a different part. Probably involving a cast to `int`. Please share a wider scope of your actual attempt.

Comment: Oh actually true, for some reason the debugger was insisting in this line.

Answer (score 1):

try `if "HAP" in _prts[3]`

Edit: I tried your code with your values `_file = "asdfads_afsd_fads_ANG_adfs"` and it worked fine (python 3.8.1)

Comment: After more careful debugging I figure out that the issue is in another line (just the debugger was complaining in this line)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell you what's the problem without knowing what is the real content in _prts.

What I would try to use is str(), as follows:

```
_prts = _file.split("_")
if (str(_prts[3]) == "HAP"):
        label = 1
elif (str(_prts[3]) == "SAD"):
        label = 2
elif (str(_prts[3]) == "ANG"):
        label = 3
```

Comment: After more careful debugging I figure out that the issue is in another line (just the debugger was complaining in this line).